# Regular Domain Of $C^{\infty}$

Tags: geometry, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Please, someone can explain for me what is a bounded domain of class $C^{\infty}$.

And could you give me an example to see the difference between domain and bounded domain of class $C^{\infty}$.

Many thanks!.

Comment: Context is everything in abbreviated definition queries of this kind.  Where did you see the phrase used?

Answer (score 0):

Bounded domain : ball $B(0,1)$. Unbounded domain half plane $\mathbb{H}^n$.